# caret doMPI error

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm getting a "object 'requireNamespaceQuietStop' not found" error when running models via caret using Rmpi. I am able to run the models just fine without Rmpi.

Here's a minimal example:

```r
> library(mlbench)
> library(doMPI)
> library(caret)
> set.seed(998)
> cl <- startMPIcluster(count=8)
    8 slaves are spawned successfully. 0 failed.
> registerDoMPI(cl)
> data(Sonar)
> inTraining <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class, p = .75, list = FALSE)
> training <- Sonar[ inTraining,]
> testing  <- Sonar[-inTraining,]
> fitControl <- trainControl(
   method = "repeatedcv",
   number = 10,
   repeats = 10)
> gbmFit1 <- train(Class ~ ., data = training, 
                  method = "gbm", 
                  trControl = fitControl,
                  verbose = FALSE)
Error in { : 
  task 2 failed - "object 'requireNamespaceQuietStop' not found"
>
```

Also, here's my session info:

```r
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] caret_6.0-79    ggplot2_2.2.1   lattice_0.20-35 doMPI_0.2.2     Rmpi_0.6-7      iterators_1.0.9
[7] foreach_1.4.4   mlbench_2.1-1   h2o_3.18.0.8   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.16       lubridate_1.7.4    tidyr_0.8.0        class_7.3-14       assertthat_0.2.0  
 [6] glmnet_2.0-16      ipred_0.9-6        psych_1.8.3.3      R6_2.2.2           plyr_1.8.4        
[11] magic_1.5-8        reprex_0.1.2       stats4_3.5.0       e1071_1.6-8        pillar_1.2.2      
[16] rlang_0.2.0        lazyeval_0.2.1     kernlab_0.9-26     rpart_4.1-13       Matrix_1.2-14     
[21] splines_3.5.0      CVST_0.2-1         ddalpha_1.3.3      gower_0.1.2        stringr_1.3.0     
[26] foreign_0.8-70     RCurl_1.95-4.10    munsell_0.4.3      broom_0.4.4        compiler_3.5.0    
[31] pkgconfig_2.0.1    mnormt_1.5-5       dimRed_0.1.0       gbm_2.1.3          nnet_7.3-12       
[36] tidyselect_0.2.4   tibble_1.4.2       prodlim_2018.04.18 DRR_0.0.3          codetools_0.2-15  
[41] RcppRoll_0.2.2     dplyr_0.7.4        withr_2.1.2        MASS_7.3-49        bitops_1.0-6      
[46] recipes_0.1.2      ModelMetrics_1.1.0 grid_3.5.0         nlme_3.1-137       jsonlite_1.5      
[51] gtable_0.2.0       magrittr_1.5       scales_0.5.0       stringi_1.1.7      reshape2_1.4.3    
[56] bindrcpp_0.2.2     timeDate_3043.102  robustbase_0.93-0  geometry_0.3-6     lava_1.6.1        
[61] tools_3.5.0        glue_1.2.0         DEoptimR_1.0-8     purrr_0.2.4        sfsmisc_1.1-2     
[66] abind_1.4-5        parallel_3.5.0     survival_2.41-3    yaml_2.1.18        colorspace_1.3-2  
[71] knitr_1.20         bindr_0.1.1
```

Has anyone else had this error? Is there a workaround?